# IOS: [NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, key, nsdictionary

In my project i created a dictionary with objects and keys
i create NSArray for both objects and keys

But when i try to create dictionary it send the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (2) differs from count of
>   keys (12)'

but i am sending all 12 objects to the dictionary

My code is:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"api_key", @"truck_id",@"driver_id", @"member_id",@"amount",@"net_amount",@"vendor_id",@"delivery_date",@"address_id", @"create_Id", @"transaction_id",@"Cart_Details", nil];

NSLog(@"Truck Id Str is %@",TruckIdStr);
NSLog(@"Driver Id is %@",DriverIdStr);
NSLog(@"Member Id is %@",Member_id);
NSLog(@"Amount is %@",amount);
NSLog(@"Grand Total is %@",GrandTotalString);
NSLog(@"Vendor Id is %@",vendor_id);
NSLog(@"delivery date is %@",delivery_date);
NSLog(@"Address Id is %@",RcvdAddressId);
NSLog(@"Create Id is %@",create_Id);
NSLog(@"Transaction Id is %@",Transaction_Id);
NSLog(@"Selected Item array is %@",SelectedItemsArray);


NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6",TruckIdStr,DriverIdStr,Member_id,amount,GrandTotalString,vendor_id,delivery_date,RcvdAddressId,create_Id,Transaction_Id,SelectedItemsArray, nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@",dictionary);
```

In console Area it display nslog values as:

```
 Truck Id Str is 
 Driver Id is (null)
 Member Id is 269
 Amount is 10
 Grand Total is 30.06
 Vendor Id is 447
 delivery date is 2017/07/21
 Address Id is 37
 Create Id is 2017-07-21T05:43:06Z
 Transaction Id is PAY-1RA1614620154883CLFYZI2Q
 Selected Item array is (
        {
        TotalPrice = "0.06";
        UnitPrice = "0.02";
        VendorId = 447;
        itemId = 75;
        itemQuantity = 3;
        name = "Green-Chile Burgers with Fried Eggs";
    },
        {
        TotalPrice = 30;
        UnitPrice = 10;
        VendorId = 447;
        itemId = 77;
        itemQuantity = 3;
        name = TestRohit11;
    }
)
```

Comment: it's because your values coming nil, and nsarray close where nil comes

Comment: try to do empty value in place of nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its due to NULL value.**

Here is your code which crash your app:

```
 NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"api_key", @"truck_id",@"driver_id", @"member_id",@"amount",@"net_amount",@"vendor_id",@"delivery_date",@"address_id", @"create_Id", @"transaction_id",@"Cart_Details", nil];

//    @"DriverIdStr"
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6",@"TruckIdStr",NULL,@"Member_id",@"amount",@"GrandTotalString",@"vendor_id",@"delivery_date",@"RcvdAddressId",@"create_Id",@"Transaction_Id",@"SelectedItemsArray", nil];
```

If I give **NULL** , my application is crashed.

Correct Code:

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6",@"TruckIdStr",@"DriverIdStr",@"Member_id",@"amount",@"GrandTotalString",@"vendor_id",@"delivery_date",@"RcvdAddressId",@"create_Id",@"Transaction_Id",@"SelectedItemsArray", nil];
```

**If you need to replace to Blank string if there is NULL in it.**

Replace NULL string into blank:

```
  NSString* strValue = NULL;
if (strValue == nil || strValue == (id)[NSNull null]) {
    // Set Blank to string
    strValue = @"";
} else {
    // You don't have NULL in your string, so you can use it directly
}
```

Comment: @Yatendra you cannot add NULL into NSDictionary. I give you both example. In first example, I tried to add using NULL its give me error. in Second, I will pass some value into string, its work fine. Also check my udpated code to remove null from string.

Comment: @Yatendra I posted proper explanation along with your solutions. My answer shouldn't be down vote.

Comment: @Yatendra You should post an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JamesP sometimes needs to guide not already baked food, and I think question is general concept of ios, so we just need to guide and understand that.